# VBA show BOTH results and formula (for audit purposes) in the cell

Tags: vba, formula

I need help with my puzzle. I have written a code that works fine. Now a user wants to see not just the final result but also the formula written in VBA (for audit purposes) to verify that the results are OK. Is there a way to show BOTH results and formula in the same cell?

My code so far:

```
Sub Vlookup_Condition_VAT_table()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("GST_recovery_overclaim.xlsm").Worksheets("MonthlyData_Raw").Activate

'Identify the Destination location to start populating vlookuped values

Range("AK2").Activate

With Worksheets("MonthlyData_Raw").Cells
    Set Rng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    For i = 2 To Rng.Rows.Count

    'populate the destination range with
    'vlookup values from the list vlookup table

        Rng.Cells(i, 37) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 28), Sheets("VAT_apportionment_table_201310").Range("D:G"), 4, False)

    Next
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thank you very much,
Russ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't looking at thousands of rows, you could try the following.

Instead of using this line to print the result of your vlookup formula:

```
Rng.Cells(i, 37) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 28), Sheets("VAT_apportionment_table_201310").Range("D:G"), 4, False)
```

You could instead put the actual formula in the cell with this change

```
Rng.Cells(i, 37).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & _
          .Cells(i, 28).Address & "," & _
          "'" & Sheets("VAT_apportionment_table_201310").name & "'!D:G," & _
          "4," & _
          "False)"
```

--------------UPDATE BASED ON OP COMMENT-----------------------------

Adding error trapping via an `ISERROR` function (untested)

```
Dim errMsg as String
errMsg = "Not in exception list"
Rng.Cells(i, 37).Formula = "=ISERROR(VLOOKUP(" & _
          .Cells(i, 28).Address & "," & _
          "'" & Sheets("VAT_apportionment_table_201310").name & "'!D:G," & _
          "4," & _
          "False), " & errMsg & ")"
```

I created a variable for the error message for a couple of reasons.

1. Easier to debug later
2. Dealing with text in a formula that is being sent to the cell like this can be tricky. And using a variable gets around the trickiness.

Comment: Guitarthrower, yes, it works. Now I have another challenge: add either ISERROR or IFERROR and state that in case of error, provide me with "Not in exception list" statement in the line. I have been lost with "" and &&&. Could you help me? I would appreciate if you could explain to me how "" and & work. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add text to the result with the answer and the formula.

```
Rng.Cells(i, 37) = "Answer: " & Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 28), Sheets("VAT_apportionment_table_201310").Range("D:G"), 4, False) & ", Formula: = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 28), Sheets("VAT_apportionment_table_201310").Range("D:G"), 4, False)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood you correctly, you want to display the formula entered in a cell with the result. How about this?

```
   'Assume that you have a Range("A1") equals to = cos(20)
    Sub GetFormula()
    Dim MyFormula As String
    MyFormula = Replace(Range("A1").Formula, "=", "")
    MsgBox ("Formula is : " & MyFormula _
    & " Result is :" & Range("A1"))
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm making the assumption that the formula is entered by the user, no VBA involved.

Comment: Actually the formula is added by VBA and the plan is to have the result and formula in the same cell. Thank you, ALL. i didn't have a chance to test anything yet...